# Serial comms from Arduino to RPi via pins

Tags: python, arduino, ide, raspberry-pi2, hardware

I am stuck and dont know why. I am trying to transmit from an Arduino Nano to a RPi via the TX and Rx pins respectively.

This my code so far:

Arduino TX:

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  bProgramLoop = 1
  while(bProgramLoop == 1){
    Serial.write(1);
  }
}
```

The Raspberry Side:

```
import serial
oSer = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate=9600,timeout=1)

while True:
    sSerialInput = oSer.read(1)
    #sSerialInput = oSer.readline()
    print sSerialInput
```

After loading the sketch onto the Arduino and starting the python script, the Raspberry simply does not read anything.

NOTE:

- I have connected the Tx pin from the Arduino to the Rx pin from the RPi via a Voltage divider and some jumper wires.
- I have tried "readline()" too, but no luck

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the a solution to the problem I am having. I am still a proper noob, but as far as I can figure it out, sending serial data over the Tx pin is problematic because it is used by the usb port and then to your PC.

Thus the solution is to use the SoftwareSerial library. I have modified my two code sketches as follows:

Arduino:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(4,3); // (RX,TX) - Pin Setup for any digital pins you want as Rx or Tx

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(57600); // initialize serial communication with serial pin
}

void loop(){
  bProgramLoop = 1
  while(bProgramLoop == 1){
    mySerial.write("Anything");
  }
}
```

Raspberry:

```
import serial
oSer = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate=9600,timeout=1)

while True:
    sSerialInput = oSer.readline()
    print sSerialInput
```

As it is I am able to transmit data from the Arduino to the RPi. **HOWEVER**, I am still having issues converting the string to an integer or float.

see this post for details: [Python readline() returns string that wont convert to int or float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800225/python-readline-returns-string-that-wont-convert-to-int-or-float)