# Python readline() returns string that wont convert to int or float

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I am using  Arduino SoftwareSerial library to send serial data to a Raspberry Rx pin. I can get the Arduino serial data sent over to the Raspberry successfully, in as much that the integers I sent arrive as the equivalent in a string.

The problem:

I am trying to convert the string that the .readline() returns into a float or int, but I am unable to do so.

```
import serial
oSer = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate=57600,timeout=1)

while True:
    sInput = oSer.readline()
    print sInput #Returns: >>1,2,3,

    lsInput = sInput.split(',')
    print lsInput #Returns: >>['1','2','3','\r\n']
```

How can I convert this to an int or float? I simply need to do some arithmetic with the numbers. I have tried:

```
    lfInput = [float(i) for i in lsInput] #Returns: >> ValueError: could not convert to float:

    liInput = [int(i) for i in lsInput] #Returns: >> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

**The Answer**

Thanks to John and Padraic who provided Answers, I can confirm an update on how to fix the above problem. I prefer Padraic's solution, slightly more elegant, but either work. I added the following:

John's and especially Pad's solution (see answers below for better and more detail):

```
sInput = oSer.readline().strip() #but see answers below from Pad for more detail
```

Comment: Is that trailing `,` going to be consistent?

Comment: What happens when you get more than three numbers?

Comment: Mark: the trailing "comma" i deliberately put into the Arduino sketch initially to separate the trailing '\r\n' term. but that comma is no longer needed.

Comment: Padraic: Nothing, the amount of numbers i get from the Arduino sketch will always be the same. My code on either end will account for a set number of numbers. I hope :) thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Misha pls post the answer as an answer an not as edit of your question.

Comment: This can be quite annoying, when I posted an answer as an Answer I got told not not by admin peeps. Now you are asking me to..... there seems to be very little consistency here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by the `\r\n` at the end of the line.  `int()` and `float()` don't like that.

You can either strip it off like so:

```
sInput = oSer.readline().strip()
```

Or you can modify the loop to ignore non-numbers:

```
liInput = [int(i) for i in lsInput if i.isdigit()]
```

Comment: Hi John. This is an excellent solution thanks. Very elegant doing it with the strip method. Thanks mills man! much appretiated

Comment: To be clear, `int` and `float` ignore whitespace; it's not that they have a problem with `\r\n`, it's that they require at least one digit. Since the input has a trailing comma `split` ends up leaving a string that contains no digits at all. `int("1\r\n")` would work just fine, it's `int("\r\n")` that fails.

Answer (score 1):

You can `rstrip` the trailing white space:

```
while True:
    sInput = oSer.readline().rstrip().split(",")
```

Or a more robust approach is to see if an element can be cast to a float using a try/except:

```
def cast(it):
    for ele in it:
        try:
            yield float(ele)
        except ValueError:
            pass


while True:
    sInput = oSer.readline().rstrip(",\r\n").split(",")
    nums = list(cast(sInput.split(",")))
```

`cast` will work for floats, ints and negative numbers.

Comment: Thanks Padraic, I will give this a try.

Comment: @Misha, *isdigit* will only work for positive integers, `"1.0".isdigit() -> False`, `"-1".isdigit() -> False`, if you are 100 percent positive you won't have negative numbers or floats then it is sufficient.

Comment: I will never have negative numbers, but that does not mean that my model should not be expanded to that which is better. Thanks

Comment: Padraic, regarding the function "cast(it)"; you have not called it anywhere? Sor if this is a seriously noob question, relatively new to python.

Comment: It should be, `list(cast(sInput.split(",")))`, it is a generator function that gives you a list of numbers